# Check if Request is Get, Post, Put or Delete in Exception Handler class

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am using java and Spring Boot to create a basic REST API.
How would I check if a request is any of this {GET, POST, PUT, DELETE}?

This is the method in the exception handler.

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Component
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

      @Override
      protectedResponseEntity<Object>handleHttpMessageNotReadable(
      HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus 
      status, WebRequest request) {

       String error = "Not a JSON object";


       ExceptionResponse response = ExceptionResponse.getBuilder()
                                    .addVerb("POST")
                                    .addURL(Global.URL)
                                    .addMessage(error).build();
       return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
      }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cast your `WebRequest` into `HttpServletRequest` and find the method.

```
((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod();
```

**Edit** :

As per the comment OP's handler is not invoked. 
Below is an example of Exception Handler with Order precedence.

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {    

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        ((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod();

        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add that line, it breaks the method somehow. It does not return the proper message. Somehow the default handler takes precedence.

Comment: @DheerajDhall Not sure as you have not shared full code of your handler. Although,  I have updated my answer to demonstrate a complete request handler which also has highest precedence.

Comment: @DheerajDhall If this doesn't work, provide the full code of your handler

Comment: I updated the question. I do have ordered precedence annotation

Comment: @DheerajDhall - That is still not the full code for the handler.  And it certainly doesn't show that you have done what Amit suggested that you do.  (There should be a call to getMethod, etcetera.)

Comment: I updated it to the full Handler class I currently have. The problem is if I add ((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod(); it does not work. Without that everything else works but I do not know how to get the type of request.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using this

```
((ServletWebRequest) request).getMethod();
```

Comment: I think the problem maybe was that it was causing a null pointer exception or some kind of exception somewhere. Not too sure.  But what is the difference between ServletWebRequest and HttpServletRequest?